# Get functions parameter names JS

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know how to get parameter names, for example:

```
function func(sep='\n') {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

func("Arg1", "Argument2", "Something", sep="MySeparator")

// I want to get value of "sep" in arguments of function
// In this example it should set optional parameter "sep" to "MySeparator"
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: You want to get "Arg1", "Argument2", "Something" in your function not their values?

Comment: I believe this syntax comes from Python. If I'm right, it is not possible in JavaScript. You can use named arguments like `function func({args, sep}) {}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but seems like you want to implement something like this:

```js
function func(separator = '\n', ...args) {
  return args.join(separator);
}

console.log(func(' - MySeparator - ', 'Arg1', 'Arg2', 'Arg3'));
```

The first argument in `func` accepts a separator you want to use, while all other arguments will be passed as an array into the function where you can use `join` to glue them together with your separator.

**UPD1**: **Why we can not accept spread argument first and then the separator at the end?**

As stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> A function's last parameter can be prefixed with ... which will cause all remaining (user supplied) arguments to be placed within a "standard" Javascript array. Only the last parameter can be a "rest parameter".

Short explanation for this case: we don't know if the developer passed the argument into `separator` or the rest arguments. That is why we consuming the known positional arguments to match them to their appropriate variable names and only then we can consume "everything that left".

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i want to add "...args" as first argument and "separator" as last. I don't know whether this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t get name of arguments, if you want name/value pairs as arguments then try to pass it as an object like show below.

```
function func(args) {
     args.arg1;
     args.arg2;
}

func({ arg1: “some value”, arg2: “other value” });
```

Comment: Thanks, with this i am also able to do what i want :P